# Reading Glue Catalog from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue

Is it possible to connect lambda to glue data catalog to query the data within the catalog tables? If yes, how do I connect it?
I am trying to connect Glue catalog to Lambda function to query the tables, but not able to find any information on it.
It would be helpful if someone can provide any resource or code for it.

Comment: What is your preferred programming language? Here it is for Python: [Glue - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html)